# plot a surface using plot3d etc within a sphere

Tags: plotting, constraint, implicit

I recently need to plot a 3d function that satisfies certain constraints, like

```
x^2+y^2+z^2<=1
```

or things similar. So I wonder how to plot the part that only lies within the constraints?

An example surface can be

```
z=x^2-y^2
```

More interestingly, is it possible to do that for an implicit function, e.g.   x^2+y^2-z^3-z=0, without solving for the equation?
   Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use [`RegionFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction.html) to restrict the region of a plot

Comment: @SimonWoods Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@SimonWoods hit the nail on the head here:

```
Plot3D[x^2 - y^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0 - 1, 1}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1]]
```

[image]

Or with your implicit surface:

```
ContourPlot3D[
 x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - z == 0, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1]]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, it works great, thanks!